# Performance not good on Playing video using url

Tags: android

I'm using LIbVlc2.1.12 library to play video using url. But it is taking time in buffering even in WiFi also.

I also tried VideoView , SurfaceView. LibVlc2.1.12 is better than both.

But I want improve streaming process. Please suggest me any other best way rather than I have used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various 3rd party video players such as jwplayer or exoplayer

Comment: will you please suggest me best. i have tried easy_video_playe, exo,jw is paid. looking for free.

Comment: Exoplayer offers a lot of customizations. You can try that